# How do I prevent substitution before processing in TCL?

Tags: tcl, command-substitution

I'm calling a TCL procedure like this-

```
::f::abstract -procname my_proc -args "-arg1 $a -arg2 $b"
```

Now here `$a` itself is something like this-

```
"ping -c 1 10.1.1.$ip"
```

When I try to run this, `$a` is expanded, and it becomes-

```
-args "-arg1 ping -c 1 10.1.1.27 -arg2 a2"
```

This gives an error because now it appears we have additional arguments like -c.

What I want is to take in `$a` as as a whole, and later on expand it inside the procedure.

How do I do that?

I can't use `{}` brackets because I need variable substitution. I can't remove quotes because the outer quotes take in `args`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to quoting horrors.

If you expand it properly in the procedure, treat it like a proper list:

```
::f::abstract -procname my_proc -args [list -arg1 $a -arg2 $b]
```

This gets passed to your proc exactly like you can expect: as four things:

- the string `-arg1`
- the list/script `ping - c1 10.1.1.$ip`
- the string `-arg2`
- the string <whatever `$b` expands to>

Inside your proc, you will have to again `eval` your arg1's 'a' value, just as you expect (I hope, multiple evaluation is given in your structure here).

```
proc ... args {
    array set options <defaults>
    array set options $args
    set a [uplevel 1 $options(-arg1)]
    ...
    # $a now has a useful value...
}
```

Comment: The `{*}` expansion syntax can help a lot with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
::f::abstract -procname my_proc -args [list -arg1 $a -arg2 $b]
```

It allows substitution but preserves the list structure of the command line. I.e. you still have the same number of arguments on each level.